# Where do I find DocumentRoot on Ubuntu after installing PHP, MySQL and Apache2?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-13.10

I am new to Ubuntu Linux (version 13.10). I am following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioqa-ZT-WSg) to install MySQL, PHP, and Apache2.

It installed successfully, but I don't know where to write PHP files that execute when you navigate to the URL `localhost/example.php`.

I am looking at [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-unix-linux-apache-documentroot/), but I am afraid that maybe it will not work and have to reinstall Ubuntu again.

Comment: `/var/www` is the path mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: it's for a local development server or a webserver ? if local go for xampp (lamp for linux) then update lamp/etc/extra/httpd-xamp.conf to create alias

Answer (score 16):

In a newer version should be in a different path: **/var/www/html**

With a series of commands you can find:

```
 ls /etc/apache2/sites-available/
```

That answers with something like

```
 000-default.conf  default-ssl.conf
```

In this case you need the second file `default-ssl.conf`; with

```
 grep -n -e "DocumentRoot"  /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

you can obtain:

```
 5:              DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

That means you can find (and change) `DocumentRoot` definition in the 5-th lines of the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`.

Answer (score 3):

As a simple Google search would have showed you, it's (by default), `/var/www/`.
In the Ubuntu default config, that is defined in the default virtual host, the config file for that is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

Answer (score 2):

The default location of document root is `/var/www`. This, assuming you haven't touched the HTTPd configuration.

By the way, if you simply need a development server for PHP scripts, you can use the one emebedded in PHP > 5.4. Just `cd` to the project directory and launch:

```
php -S localhost:8008
```

Answer (score 0):

In vscode (I'm sure in other editors as well) you can right click the file and copy path and copy relative path.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/site.php

Works for me.